# Are Windows Server permission unreliable?

Tags: file-permissions, windows-server-2012

We are using a Windows Server 2012 at work to share files among employees. Some of the files that need to be stored are sensitive, so we restrict read access to only a handful of people.

However, someone told me you can't rely on WS to retain permissions; that it suddenly and for no reason may suddenly change permissions, so restricted files become accessible for more people than intended.

This would have disastrous consequences for the company, so we need to be 100% sure that permissions are retained (disregarding human errors from an administrator! I'm talking purely technical weaknesses.)

Is it true WS can't be trusted? If so, what are my options? Are there other file systems that can be run? (Our services are run in an all-Windows environment so Unix file systems are probably not an option.)

Comment: I'm a hardcore Linux enthusiast and as such, not very fond of Windows, but I don't believe that permissions win WS change _automagically_...

Answer (score 0):

Consider such a situation:

- There is a folder with explicit NTFS set (inheritance turned off) and there is a user that have a permission to delete this folder.
- The user accidentally moves the folder to another NTFS volume.
- The user notices his mistake and moves the folder back.

If no other user notices the mistake, the folder seems untouched, but now the permission list has been reset and inherited after the folder's parent.

Answer (score -1):

I'd really like to say WS permissions are secure as there **IS NO LOGICAL REASON WHY THEY SHOULD CHANGE OVER TIME!**

But.....

I have had the same problem, not with permissions adding themselves, but with permissions removing themselves. A previously accessible folder will suddenly become inaccessible and on further inquiry, previously added permissions will be removed.

This does not happen often by any means, but it does happen (in our Windows Server 2008 R2 environment anyway), so my answer would be "**no**", WS permissions are not 100% reliable.